# Copy values from one table to another, only where second table has specific values

Tags: r, dplyr, sapply

I thought this would be straightforward, but it's been a while since I've looked at R.

I have two tables, and I want to make a third table with values from the first based on values from the second. (I want the numbers from table 1, anytime the corresponding row/column from table 2 has a "1")

I was thinking `sapply` or `lapply` would probably be what I need, or something from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr)?  Just not sure how.

Table 1 (df1):

```
row  sample.1  sample.2  sample.3
1       55       6788      4003
2     9000        135      1200
3     3400       2000      7500
4       92        348       227  
5     4286       2731      6298
```

Table 2 (df2):

```
row  sample.1  sample.2  sample.3
1        0          1         1
2        1          0         0
3        1          1         1
4        0          0         0  
5        1          1         1
```

Table 3 ( df3 - desired output):

```
row  sample.1  sample.2  sample.3
1        0       6788      4003
2     9000          0         0
3     3400       2000      7500
4        0          0         0  
5     4286       2731      6298
```

Comment: Do you have a column `row` or it is just rownames

Comment: Sorry, just the row names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easier option would be an elementwise multiplication as these are numeric columns and because any number multiplied by 0 returns 0 while those multiplied by 1 gives the number itself (assuming both datasets have same dimensions

```
df1 * df2
```

If 'row' is the first column, subset the datasets by removing the first column and `cbind` with the first column of any of the datasets

```
cbind(df1[1], df1[-1] * df2[-1])
```

Comment: *smacks forehead* Brilliant!